# Does MySQL have built-in escaping functionality?

Tags: mysql, security, escaping

I am now using my 100th (ok, exaggerated) language&framework combination with MySQL. It seems almost silly, and also very risky, to me that every single one of these tools provides their own escaping functionality. Does MySQL (or other SQL solutions) not offer that themselves? What if there is a little bug in one such customized escape functions? Why should we have to trust third party providers to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL *has* connectors and APIs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connectors-apis.html) including functions like [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) and programming languages *are* just adapting them.

Comment: What about [this thing with double question-marks to escape identifiers](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-identifiers). This seems custom? Or why does he say >"Please note that this last character sequence is experimental and syntax might change"?

Comment: @Domi The placeholder `??` for identifiers is experimental in [Felix Geisendörfer’s *node-mysql*](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

Comment: That's too bad! Maybe it will make it into the standard some day.